# Green cover with water noise inside

Tags: water, sewer

[image]I have this green cover which has something inside connected to the electricity, and I have no idea what it is, but today it started to make a lot of noise.

I've lived in this house for over a year and this is new behavior. I live down a hill, so I wonder if it's something that helps bring waste water up to the main sewer line.

Anybody would have any idea what this might be?

Comment: We cannot see what you see. Take a photo and upload it into your question using the "Edit" button below the question text, and then the "Moon and Mountains" button in the text edit box.

Comment: Also need to know if it's inside, outside, where in your house it is, and if the noise is constant or intermittent.  Also would help to know if it's been very wet/rainy there recently, and how long you've lived in this location to know if this is a new behavior or not.

Comment: Sorry! The image didn't upload the first time! It has not been raining... This is new behavior.

Comment: It might be identified on the land survey that you probably did with the purchase.

Comment: M guess is something is wrong with a sprinkler system.

Comment: Take the covers off and do it again. I suspect a pipe came lose from a pump and now it's just running doing nothing. Which could be bad the next time it rains.

Comment: How do you know it's connected to electricity if is has a water noise inside?

Comment: There is writing on the green cover. What does it say? What is under the covers?

Comment: it says "Do not Enter"  and "Dangerous gas" and makes "water" and "machinery" noises. It being something for the lifting sewage seems like a reasonable guess.  But those are the only parts of the warning I can read,  what does the whole thing say?

Answer (score 1):

The writing on the cover that can be made out is consistent (as is the size) with a pumped sewage sump.

If it's making unusual noises you'll want to get it sorted out before it starts overflowing or backing up into the house. If it's done properly you might have an alarm that starts going off once the level gets too high.